# Moment js not working properly in firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, momentjs

`2020-08-05 08:01 AM UTC` , it is the format I am getting from the backend api. I need to show it in this way `Aug 5th, 2020 2:01 PM` in UI. Below is the function I am using to perform this and it is working perfectly in chrome but showing invalid date in firefox.

```
import moment from 'moment';

export const formatDate = record => {
  return moment(new Date(record)).format('MMM Do, YYYY h:mm A');
};
```

I am using this in one of my react projects. Is there any way to make this work in both browsers ?

```js
const record = "2020-08-05 08:01 AM UTC"

let s = moment(new Date(record)).format('MMM Do, YYYY h:mm A');

document.getElementById("msg").textContent = s;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: what is the format of `record` please add in your question ?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, I have also searched but still looking for a way to solve this.

Comment: OR with moment only => `let date = moment('2020-08-05 08:01 AM UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A Z' ).format('MMM Do, YYYY h:mm A');` Works on firefox

Comment: @AlwaysHelping thanks, it is working. I just had to convert it into local time